# Force a date to the first day of the month inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are a few examples on SE using DateAdd and DatePart, but none of them address my specific issue, which is how to do this with a parameter.  What I need to do is force a date parameter to use the first day of the month instead of the date passed into the parameter.  So, my truncated code looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CR_PW_Insert]
(
    @PR_STATUS int = NULL 
    ,@CASE_TYPE int = NULL
    ,@FROM_DATE date = NULL
    ,@TO_DATE date = NULL
        
)

AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        INSERT into [dbo].[tbl_CR_Premium]
        (
        PR_STATUS 
        ,CASE_TYPE
        ,FROM_DATE
        ,TO_DATE
        )
      
        VALUES 
        (
        @PR_STATUS
        ,@CASE_TYPE
        ,@FROM_DATE
        ,@TO_DATE
        );

        COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        BEGIN  
        PRINT  
            N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +  
            'Rolling back transaction.'  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
        END;  
    END CATCH;


END

GO
```

I'm using a date picker to grab the date, but we want to store only the first date of the month that's being selected.  So, if @FROM_DATE = 4/8/2021 we actually want to write 4/1/2021 to the table.  How would I do this?

Comment: A single statement is atomic - you don't need a transaction here. You also should not be using PRINT in this manner. Let the caller of this procedure know an error occurred by either not handling the error or by re-throwing it. Your code effectively eats the error and there is no way for anyone or any other code to know exactly why the error occurred. And stop supplying nonsense default values - don't encourage lazy coding

Comment: To add to what @SMor is saying, remove the `TRY\CATCH` completely and just use `SET XACT ABORT ON;`, this ensures a rollback

Comment: The code was truncated for simplicity.  I'm not looking for coding advice, I'm looking for an answer to a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "truncate" the date to the first day of the month by using some anchor date. For example, 1st of Jan 2000.

```
SET @FROM_DATE =
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '2000-01-01', @FROM_DATE), '2000-01-01')
```

This will work with any types: `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2`.

It works because `DATEDIFF` returns the count of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate. For example, `DATEDIFF(month, '2000-01-31', '2000-02-01')` returns 1.

Answer (score 3):

**`DATEFROMPARTS` is usually the best way of doing this:**

```
SET @FROM_DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@FROM_DATE), MONTH(@FROM_DATE), 1);
```

Comment: How would you compare this to Vladimir's answer, in terms of stability or usability?  Honestly, Vladimir's answer worked fine, but this feels better since it's not based on any year the way his is based on the year 2000.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, `DATEFROMPARTS` was added in SQL Server 2012. This is important only for those who still use the previous versions, though. Besides, the `DATEADD / DATEDIFF` approach can be used to truncate the `date/time` to any unit: year, month, week, day.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov As can `DATEFROMPARTS/DATETIMEFROMPARTS`. And anyone on SQL Server 2008 or earlier needs their head checked anyway

Comment: @JohnnyBones To each their own, I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @FROM_DATE), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

This should work.

So you could do this at the start of your stored procedure.

```
SET @FROM_DATE = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @FROM_DATE), 0)
```

Then run your code normally.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, only because I did not see it as an option.

Since it will be resolved only once, `format()` should be considered.

```
Set @FROM_DATE = format(@FROM_DATE,'yyyy-MM-01')
```